# Resources for preparing for HFI CUA

Tags: user-research

I am preparing for the HFI CUA. What resources would you recommend for me - either paid or free! Any courses on Lynda? Any particular resources/blogs that are focused on preparing for the exam.

Answer (score 0):

Refer HFI course material, I don't think you can get those resources outside. If you get the resource it's hard to understand cos they prepared course material in such a way that without attending the course it's hard to understand.